# telerik org chart collapse functionality not working

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I'm using Telerik ASP.NET OrgChart to display a simple chart organization, I've a rather small problem: my chart doesn't show any thing for expanding/collapsing the chart, so my chart (which can be large) is displayed with all nodes and it is not I want, I want to be able to hide/show my nodes so that user can navigate chart easily, I've exactly used the code in this sample:

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/orgchart-expand-collapse.html

but my chart doesn't show hide/show icons, what is going wrong? Do you I miss anything?
it is my code:

```
<%@ Register assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" tagprefix="telerik" %>

        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<telerik:RadOrgChart ID="RadOrgChart1" runat="server" EnableCollapsing="true">
    <Nodes>
        <telerik:OrgChartNode>
            <GroupItems>
                <telerik:OrgChartGroupItem Text="Item1">
                </telerik:OrgChartGroupItem>
                <telerik:OrgChartGroupItem Text="Item1">
                </telerik:OrgChartGroupItem>
            </GroupItems>
            <Nodes>
                <telerik:OrgChartNode>
                    <GroupItems>
                        <telerik:OrgChartGroupItem Text="Item1">
                        </telerik:OrgChartGroupItem>
                        <telerik:OrgChartGroupItem Text="Item1">
                        </telerik:OrgChartGroupItem>
                    </GroupItems>
                </telerik:OrgChartNode>
                <telerik:OrgChartNode Collapsed="true">
                    <GroupItems>
                        <telerik:OrgChartGroupItem Text="item1">
                        </telerik:OrgChartGroupItem>
                    </GroupItems>
                    <Nodes>
                        <telerik:OrgChartNode>
                            <GroupItems>
                                <telerik:OrgChartGroupItem Text="Item1">
                                </telerik:OrgChartGroupItem>
                                <telerik:OrgChartGroupItem Text="Item1">
                                </telerik:OrgChartGroupItem>
                            </GroupItems>
                        </telerik:OrgChartNode>
                    </Nodes>
                </telerik:OrgChartNode>
            </Nodes>
        </telerik:OrgChartNode>
    </Nodes>
</telerik:RadOrgChart>
```

I use Q3 2011, also when I want to run my code, I should remove `Collapsed="true"`, I think it is not supported, and I think it is my problem, how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have only one item in the group where the collapse property is set to true. The property "collapsed" shall be applied to each node you intend to became collapsable. In you r case you have this:

```
 <telerik:OrgChartNode Collapsed="true">
                    <GroupItems>
                        <telerik:OrgChartGroupItem Text="item1">
                        </telerik:OrgChartGroupItem>
                    </GroupItems>
```

so there is nothing to collapse in there. Try to apply the collapse property in a group with more than one item.
Reference Telerik documentation: *"The functionality could be enabled by setting EnableGroupCollapsing property to true. The functionality is available when a Node has more than one GroupItem."*

Comment: thanks, but as I said I cannot use this property at all, I think my telerik dll doesn't support it, as I said I use Q3 2011, do I miss anything?

Comment: @Ali_dotNet Sorry I overlooked the fact that is an old Dll. Actually I am not sure too if the Q3 2011 supports this property. Can you open a ticket on Telerik?

Comment: oh thanks, I'll do it soon, but isn't there any way that I can have a expandable/collapseable org chart in Q3 2001? or do you know any other free tools?

Comment: @Ali_dotNet I checked this movie on Telerik TV dated december 2011 and there is no evidence of such collapsable feature. http://tv.telerik.com/search?keywords=radorgchart. So you may be correct about the fact that the feature is not there. I am not aware of other free controls with such feature.

Comment: thanks for your time, I've posted a question in telerik forum, I hope they can suggest me a solution, what is the minimum version that supports this feature? do you know perhaps?

Comment: @Ali_dotNet I started using Telerik with Q2 2013 and the feature was there. I do not know when it was introduced.

Comment: thanks Felice, I switched to 2012 Q2, and it seems OK now! you helped me a lot.